# how to match a text including special characters in using regex in oracle

Tags: regex, oracle

I have this text:
`Process explanation: plasma gasification with 50% alcohol added. Final activity for manager: some activity`.
I just wanna grab this part: `plasma gasification with 50% alcohol added`. Sometimes this exist: `Final activity for manager: some activity` and sometimes it doesn't. The part extracted may contain any special characters: `plasma gasification with 50% alcohol added`.

I just want to grab any part after `Process explanation` but not including `Final activity..`

I have this so far:

```
select regexp_substr('Process explanation: plasma gasification combined with centrifugal activity. Final activity for manager: some activity',
       '(.*process[[:space:]]*(explanation)?[[:space:]]*:[[:space:]]*)(.*)([[:space:]]*final[[:space:]]*activity[[:space:]]*for[[:space:]]*manager.*$)?',
                     1, 1, 'i', 3) as extracted from dual;
```

Comment: In order to write a regular expression, you must first express in English what the rules are that you're trying to match, not just examples. So what are the rules you want to use?

Comment: This site is something I use almost every time I am making a regex. Not mine obviously, but highly recommend for beginners and advanced users alike: https://regex101.com

Comment: @AndyLester the rule is part of the question. Any part after `Process explanation` but not including `Final activity`

Comment: @IndevSmiles unfortunately that website doesn't have oracle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
Process\s+explanation\s*:\s*(.*?)(\.\s*Final activity|$)
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/T76Jjo/1). *Details*:

- `Process` - a word
- `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
- `explanation` - another word
- `\s*:\s*` - a colon enclosed with zero or more whitespaces
- `(.*?)` - Group 1: any zero or more chars as few as possible
- `(\.\s*Final activity|$)` - Group 2: either `.`, zero or more whitespaces, and `Final activity` or end of string.

In Oracle, you can use

```sql
select regexp_substr('Process explanation: plasma gasification combined with centrifugal activity. Final activity for manager: some activity',
       'process\s+explanation\s*:\s*(.*?)(\.\s*Final activity|$)',
        1, 1, 'i', 1) as extracted from dual;
```

The `i` option makes the pattern case insensitive and the last `1` argument tells Oracle to get the first capturing group value as output.

See a demo screenshot:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for this. This is much more cleaner. For this: `(.*?)`, why are we doing as few as possible. Why not `(.*)`

Comment: @jamespow `.*` will grab the whole text till the end of string, and the pattern inside the second group will trigger `$` matching, i.e. it will "overmatch" even if there is `Final activity` text. We want to match up to the `Final activity` or end of string, hence the lazy dot is required here. Fortunately, Oracle regex supports lazy quantifiers, unlike POSIX regex flavor.

Comment: Consider just `.*?:` instead of `Process\s+explanation\s*:`

Answer (score 0):

You do not need (slow) regular expressions and can use simple string functions:

```sql
SELECT CASE
       WHEN start_pos = 0
       THEN NULL
       WHEN end_pos = 0
       THEN SUBSTR(value, start_pos + start_len)
       ELSE SUBSTR(value, start_pos + start_len, end_pos - start_pos - start_len)
       END AS match
FROM   (
  SELECT value,
         INSTR(
           UPPER(value),
           UPPER(match_start),
           1
         ) AS start_pos,
         LENGTH(match_start) AS start_len,
         INSTR(
           UPPER(value),
           UPPER(match_end),
           INSTR(UPPER(value), UPPER(match_start), 1, 1)
         ) AS end_pos
  FROM   table_name
         CROSS JOIN (
           SELECT 'Process explanation:' AS match_start,
                  'Final activity' AS match_end
           FROM   DUAL
         )
)
```

*Note: if the sub-strings you want to match are always in the same case then you do not need to use `UPPER`.*

*Note 2: If you want to remove leading and trailing spaces then use the `TRIM` function on the output.*

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (value) AS
SELECT 'Process explanation: plasma gasification with 50% alcohol added. Final activity for manager: some activity' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | MATCH |
> | --- |
> | `plasma gasification with 50% alcohol added.` |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=ad9b2a3bcad228c6a1a69ba1e69e8b85)*